# Python twtter-bot hosting?

Tags: python, hosting, tweepy

I built a python weather using tweepy and it works fine but it needs me to run the script with my computer.
How can I deploy my python script on a 'server' or something so I don't need to run the script 24/7 on my laptop ?
Thanks for help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your internet connection is stable and you don't mind initial cost: Raspberry Pi.
If you are a student you can get $50 store credit at Digital Ocean through the GitHub Education Pack.
If you have a credit card and don't mind verifying (doesn't cost and has no subscription costs) you can use the free tier in Google's cloud. With a verified CC you can host on Heroku 24/7 for the entire month. Without a verified CC you can host it 24/7 for ~2-3 weeks every month. AWS also offers some free tier solution.

You can also just outright pay for a VPS every month. I currently use Vultr and pay $2.5 per month.

Answer (score 3):

You could buy a raspberry pi.
I use it only for such things.
electricity: ~2-4W
It isn't that expensive and you can host many projects for a low price.